# double_click method is not working in firefox

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

double_click method to doubleclick is not working with firefox browser.  As it displays the below error message.  The same method works fine with chrome browser.

## Error Message:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not get node for element - cannot interact.
>           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2520-nez9f5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.j
>   s:9918:3:in `generateErrorForNativeEvents'
>           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2520-nez9f5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.j
>   s:10037:7:in`FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseDoubleClick'
>           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2520-nez9f5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
>   js:11612:16:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
>           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2520-nez9f5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
>   js:11617:7:in`DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
>           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/Niresh/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141004-2520-nez9f5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.
>   js:11559:5:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in`assert_ok'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in`new'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in`request'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in`raw_execute'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `execute'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:381:in`doubleClick'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:22:in `double_click'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:344:in`block in perform'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in`perform'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:150:in `double_click'

Comment: What version of firefox?

Comment: currently using ff31 browser